# TextBlock over a listview: how to ignore clicks in the TextBlock and let the listview handle them

Tags: wpf, events, controls, mouse, hittest

I have a listview which displays a lot of info, but when it's empty I want to overlay a textblock over it which says "No Info to Display" or "Do bla-bla-bla to add info".

The listview is set up to respond to mouse clicks, but now if I click on the textblock, those events are routed to the textblock.  How can I make these events go to the listview instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.asp)`= "false"` on the TextBlock.